# How to resample a time series producing its geometric mean?

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I'm new to Python and I just came cross a tricky question when using `pandas` to resample some data.

When I want to resample my time series data, it is very straightforward to apply the arithmetic mean function.

For example:

Suppose `ts` is time series data in minute frequency (in `pandas`, this is encapsulated in a `pandas.Series` object with a `DatetimeIndex`).

To get arithmetic mean over each group of 5 minute periods, it is simply:

```
ts.resample('5min', how='mean')
```

However, how would I compute the geometric mean in this way? Is there a simple solution like above, for example:

```
ts.resample('5min', how='gmean')
```

Comment: What class is `ts`? Are you using any non-built-in libraries? numpy, scipy, etc?

Comment: A simple way to find out is likely to read the documentation, and maybe the code.

Comment: Docs are here I believe: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html

Comment: ts probably stands for time series.

Comment: Some additional context from your code would make it much easier to answer your question

Comment: The question is clear. Why the close votes? I suppose it's a bit unclear that the OP is using `pandas`, but it *is* tagged as such.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a callable object (in this case a function) to `how`, as long as it returns a scalar:

```
In [31]: from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean

In [32]: import pandas.util.testing as tm

In [33]: ts = tm.makeTimeSeries()[:10]

In [34]: ts
Out[34]:
2000-01-03    0.605
2000-01-04   -0.167
2000-01-05    0.365
2000-01-06   -0.206
2000-01-07   -1.156
2000-01-10   -0.219
2000-01-11    1.704
2000-01-12   -0.148
2000-01-13    1.169
2000-01-14    0.823
Freq: B, dtype: float64

In [35]: ts.resample('2D', how=lambda x: gmean(x).item())
Out[35]:
2000-01-03    0.605
2000-01-05    0.365
2000-01-07    0.000
2000-01-09    0.000
2000-01-11    1.704
2000-01-13    0.981
dtype: float64
```

Note that you have to call the `item` method here to get a scalar result (because depending on the values you may get a `MaskedConstant`). `pandas` doesn't consider a single element `Series` to be a scalar.

Also, be careful about the results of calculations containing `nan`s or values where computing the geometric mean could return a complex value (e.g., the 4th root of a negative number; this will return `nan` in numpy).

`gmean` will turn computations like this into a 0 when you call the `item` method.

For example, this is why there are zeros at `2000-01-07` and `2000-01-09`.

At `2000-01-07` pandas fills in a `nan` for the 2nd day (remember we're doing `2D` here) so the geometric mean is computed as `ma.exp(ma.mean(ma.log([-1.156, nan])))`. Those two values are not "valid" input to `ma.log` (thus they are masked) so `ma.mean()` returns a `MaskedConstant` whose `_data` attribute is `0`, so its `item` method returns 0.